# Updating an html Input element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have some code that displays a series of buttons on a website.

```
 <input id="btnDay1" class="daybtn" type="button" value="Day 1" onclick="displayGraphicxxx (Day1)"</input>
 <input id="btnDay2" class="daybtn" type="button" value="Day 2" onclick="displayGraphicxxx (Day2)"</input>
```

I need to have the page update the buttons when a user selects a different option to:

```
 <input id="btnDay1" class="daybtn" type="button" value="Day 1" onclick="displayGraphicyyy (Day1)"</input>
 <input id="btnDay2" class="daybtn" type="button" value="Day 2" onclick="displayGraphicyyy (Day2)"</input>
```

I understand that .innerHTML will not work in this case, and when I tried using .value instead, nothing was changed.  How can I change the onclick section programmatically?

Comment: You can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5Ldsfukn/ . It changes the onCLick callback function via JS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you are a way you could do that. It is simple for your case.

`.setAttribute` gets two properties:

- the name of the attribute
- the value that is going to be assigned

```js
document.getElementById("btnDay1").setAttribute("onclick", "displayGraphicyyy (Day1)")
document.getElementById("btnDay2").setAttribute("onclick", "displayGraphicyyy (Day2)")
```

Comment: When? How? Why? how to revert?

Comment: The question asks for a way of changing the value of the `onclick` attribute. It depends on the function that he has `displayGraphicxxx` and `displayGraphicyyy` to put the code inside and call it with the proper values

Comment: Thank you.  That is precisely what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delegate to the closest common container (calendar div?) and use an event listener

Also your HTML was invalid

```js
const displayXXX = str => console.log("xxx",str);
const displayYYY = str => console.log("yyy",str);
document.getElementById("buttonDiv").addEventListener("click", (e) => { // any click in the div
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches(".daybtn")) return; // not a button
  const version = document.getElementById("whichVersion").value; // value of the select
  if (version === "xxx") displayXXX(tgt.value); 
  else if (version === "yyy") displayYYY(tgt.value);
})
```

```html
<select id="whichVersion">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
  <option value="yyy">yyy</option>
</select>
<div id="buttonDiv">
  <input id="btnDay1" class="daybtn" type="button" value="Day 1" />
  <input id="btnDay2" class="daybtn" type="button" value="Day 2" />
</div>
```